# How can I get content type from response when there is a proxy ajax call in extjs?

Tags: ajax, extjs, response, extjs5, javascript-framework

In the below code, I make a proxy ajax call to the server. When the session is active, I receive the expected json format but when the session is inactive, I receive a html file as response.

```
Ext.define('ExtDashboard.model.data', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'users.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'root',
            success : 'success',
            transform: function(data) {
                   //perform operations on data
                   return data;   
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The response html will have some text that shows the session as inactive. So I read the string from html and do further actions like redirecting to login page. But I am not sure how to get response here and extract content type especially when the response received is html instead of json

Answer (score 4):

IMHO it is better to check the [http response status code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) in the proxy's [exception](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.html#event-exception) event handler. Something like this:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/data.json',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'data'
    },
    listeners: {
        exception: function (proxy, response, operation) {
            // 401 - Unauthorized
            // 440 - Login Time-out
            
            if([401, 440].indexOf(response.status) > -1) {
                // Do something i.e. redirect to login page.
            };
        }

    }
}
```